# mvc 5 check user role

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How in mvc 5 I can found out role of logged user?

I made the user by this code

```
    private bool AddUserAndRole()
    {
        IdentityResult ir;
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
            (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        ir = rm.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Admin" };
        var result = UserManager.Create(user, "somepassword");
        UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");

        return true;
     }
```

After I loggin on site by that user. How in controller I can check if that user have role == "admin" or not? I found only one way which doesnt look works fast.

```
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var role = rm.FindByName("admin");
        bool result = User.IsInRole(role.Name); //true
```

Do we have other ways?

Comment: use Alex's answer or if your checking if a user should be allowed into the controller/webpage use [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] above your controller.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
bool result = User.IsInRole("admin")
```

Much easier. :)

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.. :-)

Comment: Damn it! I was close! :)

Comment: don't forget using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity